# Redirected files are generated with NO permission

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I have a shell  script prepared and tested successfully in testbed (linux) server, and I have moved this to my production server (under same user, group which I have used in testbed) with read/write/execute permissions. when I execute script in production it gives error, because redirect files get generated in by script (in same folder) with no permission (--------), hence my scripting gets failed.

I had not faced this problem in testbed server, I have tested my script successfully under user level only.(not root user level)

I already tried giving user/group permission for my script folder/files, and user/group are same one's that I have successfully tested in testbed Linux server.

how I moved my script to production:

```
unzip -K script.zip
chmod 777 script.zip
cd scriptfolder
./execute.sh
```

generated redirect file (gmon.out) in same script folder

```
ls -lrt
----------  1 user group 42023 May 15 10:00 gmon.out
```

expected redirected file

```
-rw-r-----  1 user group 42023 May 15 10:00 gmon.out
```

Please help

Comment: What's the output of `umask` on the production server?

Comment: You actually `chmod` after unzipping, which is unrelated to your question but useless. Moreover, in the man page, the `-K` flag mentions :  [AtheOS, BeOS, Unix only]

Comment: oops.. Production has umask 0777, where as my testlab has 0027. thanks Socowi..

Comment: I have changed umask using "umask u=rwx,g=,o=".. but I still didn't understand that I am able to change umask in user level itself, instead of root user.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because of the `umask`, as noted by Socowi in the command.

Umask dictactes the permission of any new file you create.

You can check the current value of umask with the `umask` command.

You can change the umask in your profile file (like your `.bashrc` if you use bash) with the `umask 0027` command, for instance.

For more information about umask :

- https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask
- http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/umask.1p.html